# CategoryAxis TickLabels margin jFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I want to have something like this on xAxis(CategoryAxis) tick labels with jFreechart
How do I achieve this ?

```
 |
 |
 +----------+------------------+----

                                                --> margin

         India                 China
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to have space between tick labels and axis-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [setTickLabelInsets()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setTickLabelInsets%28org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets%29) method to put a margin at the top of the tick labels.